# Is it reliable to use $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] on leading web servers (apache, nginx, IIS)

Tags: php, apache, iis, nginx

I just discovered that under apache a URL like wp-login.php/test might or might not run the wp-login.php script depending on virtual host/ directory settings. This made my code that depended on knowing which "root" script is running by parsing `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` unreliable and I am looking to avoid complex string parsing if possible.

Using something like `if $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == 'wp-login.php'` seems to be a better option but can I rely on it to work for all main web servers out there with the various php integration modes (mod_php, fastcgi, cgi)? Is there a better option that I missed?

(for context for people that wonder why I don't just add a `define`, this is a wordpress core file and I can't and don't want to modify it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foo.php/bar only works if the AcceptPathInfo-directive (or their pendants on other web servers) has been enabled.

No other configuration has impact to this behavior.

And yes, you can rely on that super-global entry.